# Rename a Class in .NET Project

Tags: rename, reflector

I have a Static Class with the name "Common". This class is used so many places within the Project..

Now, For some reasons I have to Change the Class name "Common" to "NewCommon"..

How I can rename the class, so that changes are reflects in the whole project where the "Common" class is being used????

**Note** My Project is on tfs..

Answer (score 2):

If you right click on the Class name, you will see an option called "Refactor". Hover over it and click "Rename".

Comment: Is this change the class name in all over the project??

Comment: It will change it in the loaded solution, and allow you to preview changes.

Comment: Yes, in addition to allowing you to change the name of the class, you can change references to it in comments and strings too.

Comment: As I earlier said that My Project is on tfs. I have no page with Checkout. Will this feature ask to me to checkout the page where changes have to made???

Comment: Will this reflector feature change the class name in the whole project without checkout any page..???

Comment: Any file that gets changed will be checked out and need to be checked in. That is a standard process with any source control system.

Comment: Means You say that,, the file will automatic checkout the pages??

Comment: hello.. I use the Reflector feature,, But It only change the class name  within only App_Code folder' classes..